# Why the text in TextView gets cut? (With android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog")

Tags: android

I have the following layout (very simple)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mainbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/cm_sign" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/H2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welldone" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ok2"
        style="@style/L1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/white_white_box"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/thanks" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity in the Manifest is defined as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.examples.android.calendar.crisismate2.Welldone17"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

I get the following result, as you can see the "THANKS!" gets cut

[image]

Thank you very much for any suggestion!!!

Comment: check your style l1, increase the size of that textview, or maybe check your string if you do have THANKS in it instead of THAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the combination of all of your layout parameters and/or styles does not allow more text to be shown.

Possible fixes.

Make the dialog wider.

Make the "Thanks" textview wider

Reduce margins and padding to make more room in the textview